# Push a file to multiple devices at once

Tags: python, shell, updates

I would like to manually push updates/files to devices located on different networks. I know I can run a periodic repository pull command but that is not efficient and based on fixed time intervals. I would like to setup an instant file push instead of a time based one. For example, when I upload a new file all the devices detect this OR are notified by the master an update is ready. How can I make a new file upload detected by my devices as close to instant as possible?

Comment: I would say that methods of updating change from company to company and also the type of program for example for Androids it is sth related to the Play Store which is partially involved in updates, otherwise You should first of kinda do some research on the topic and then come back when you have any issues with implementations and stuff. _Is there a way:_, well the short answer in most cases by far is "Yes, there is a way!"

Comment: You can't really do "push" updates, because most devices sit behind firewalls and can't be reached.  The devices need to PULL the updates, by phoning home to look for the latest versions.  A cron job to run once a day or once an hour will do the job.  You can have a JSON manifest of packages and version numbers, and the device can compare the current list to its installed base.

Comment: @Matiiss I did mention an idea I was leaning toward which was mentioned in my post. Basically asking for other options so I can pick the best one

Comment: @Matiiss I do see how this question may not be allowed since it is asking for suggestions which can be viewed as opinion based

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the scale of the project you're trying to accomplish, but I've set up a sort of auto-update checker in Python before. The basic idea is that you'd have a location to host the file and some way to determine if the file has been changed (I used a version number). This can be a basic web server located on the Pi. Then, each client checks the web server whenever you think it's appropriate to do an update, for example at the start of the program. If there is a version number mismatch, you can automatically pull the file from the web server, or direct the user to download it manually.

Comment: I disagree.  The OP is asking how other people do this (which is not a good SO question), and Zenith has provided an answer to that question.

Comment: @TimRoberts how should I word this to be a better SO question?

Comment: Well, the site guidelines are rather narrow.  It's not supposed to be for "design" questions, nor for questions that lead to opinions or recommendations.  It's really designed for "here is the code I wrote, it doesn't work for this reason, how can I fix it?"